Flutter Firebase search Function
In my app, I have a search function from Firestore. When I search a name in the TextField, I get what I want. When I delete the text (in the process of searching by using the backspace) and search again, I also get what I want. However when I clear the search button (by clicking on the clear Icon), and search again I don't get any results. What did I do wrong?

MY CODE
TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
 @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    sideBarController.dispose();
  }

  bool isCleared = false;
    List searchTerms = name.split(" ");

TextField(controller: searchController,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
     hintText: widget.searchHintString,
     hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade500),
     suffixIcon: searchController.text.isNotEmpty
     ? IconButton(onPressed: () {
     setState(() {
               searchController.clear();
               name.isEmpty;
               isCleared = true;
               });
               },
     icon: const Icon(
           Icons.clear_outlined,
           olor: Colors.red,
           ),
          ): null,
        ),
     onChanged: (value) {
       setState(() {name = value;});
                },
     ),
     ),

//For the ListTile (I didn't add the ListView.Builder here because I don't think it's relevant here. But I can add it if needed)

if (name.isEmpty || isCleared == true){
      return ListTile(onTap: () {....},
         title: ....//things I want to show
       }
if (searchTerms.any((element) => dataUser["FirstName"].toString().startsWith(element)) || //userData defined in the StreamBuilder and ListViewBuilder
    searchTerms.any((element) => dataUser["LastName"].toString().startsWith(element)) ||
    searchTerms.any((element) => dataUser["OtherNames"].toString().startsWith(element)))
         {return ListTile(onTap: () {....},
         title: ....//things I want to show
                       }
else return const SizedBox();
   

